# Do Visual Studio SDK Minor Version Updates require a Visual Studio Update

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix, visual-studio-sdk

In my Visual Studio Extension for VS 2019, I am currently using Visual Studio SDK version 16.0.202. This is the oldest version with Major Version 16.

If I update the version of the Visual Studio SDK, for example to 16.10, will that require users of my extension to update their version of Visual Studio as well?

Put another way, if I want my extension to support all versions of Visual Studio 2019, do I have to have to stay with the 16.0 version of the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

It is a good question, but I would be surprised if this is true. The libraries provided by Visual Studio, for your purposes specifically (extensibility), shouldn't change the major version numbers. Over the years, I have created many versions of visual studio packages, and I never had this problem. I always use the latest version of the SDK available, since they are actively fixing bugs. However, they may always screw up. Also, if you use internal Visual Studio libraries, not for extensibility, all bets are off.